# How to solve `ResolutionImpossible` error in python when downloading packages?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-3.6, gunicorn, chatterbot

I am getting this error when using `pip` to install from a requirements file.

```
C:\Users\keerthi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\healthcare\Ai-Healthcare-Chatbot-master>pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting Flask==0.12.3
  Using cached Flask-0.12.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: chatterbot==0.8.4 in c:\users\keerthi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy==1.1.11 in c:\users\keerthi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.1.11)
Collecting gunicorn==19.10.0
  Using cached gunicorn-19.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (113 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install SQLAlchemy==1.1.11 and chatterbot==0.8.4 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.


The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested SQLAlchemy==1.1.11
    chatterbot 0.8.4 depends on sqlalchemy<1.3 and >=1.2

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Comment: I got the output by installing SQLAlchemy==1.2.Thanks for your response

Answer (score 3):

One way that works for now is to use the legacy resolver. You can get the legacy resolver by (1) downgrading pip, or (2) using the `--use-deprecated` flag.

### Using an older pip version

I know that `pip==20.1.1` uses the old resolver, you could downgrade to that version.

```
pip install pip==20.1.1
```

### Using the --use-deprecated flag

You can also use the legacy resolver with newer versions of pip with this flag (I tested this with pip==22.3.1).

```
pip install --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver .......
```

(took me forever to find this flag, btw)

Comment: For anyone else using pip-compile, the option is `--resolver=legacy`.